# How can I pass multiple paramters in one

Tags: php

I want to do something like `mysite.com/?query="q1=1&q2=2&q3=3"`

Ive tried `$_GET['query']` but it shows query=q1

Comment: You could use something else than `&` as parameter separator.

Comment: Pass those as an array like `query[1]=1&query[2]=2&...` so your `$_GET['query'] ` will have array

Comment: the right way to do it is `mysite.com?q1=1&q2=2&q3=3...`, then you have them all in the `$_GET` array - `$_GET['q1']` for ex

Comment: now `_GET["query"] "q1=1
_GET["q2"] 2
_GET["q3"] 3"`

Comment: You would have to properly URL-encode the `&` characters - so doing it the right way would be `?query=%22q1%3D1%26q2%3D2%26q3%3D3%22`

Comment: What are you going to do??

Comment: You can encode the query string and for further access decode again.

Comment: Moreover it should have printed `"q1=1` not just `q1`

Comment: Remove the outer quotes. You currently have  one parameter called 'query' not three called 'q1', 'q2' etc. i.e. `/?q1=1&q2=2&q3=3`. Which is what I assume you want?

Comment: You should provide the inputs and the expected output in your question. It's hard to guess what you're trying to do. Do you want 3 parameters or 1 parameter which contain an array with 3 elements?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to generate an url with array parameters, you may use `http_build_query`

Example:

```
$params = http_build_query(array(
    "query" => array(
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
    ),
    "another_param" => "hello"
));
echo $params;
```

The example above will output *query%5B0%5D=value1&query%5B1%5D=value2&query%5B2%5D=value3&another_param=hello*

(Note that `http_build_query` does all the encoding job for you)

You will be able to use these parameters after **?** in a link:

```
echo "<a href='http://mywebsite.com/?$params'>link</a>"
```

Then you can read this parameter from `$_GET`

```
if(isset($_GET['query']) && is_array($_GET['query'])){
    foreach($_GET['query'] as $query){
        //Do something with $query value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape/urlencode the `&` because it views that as the next query string parameter.

Comment: How do you do that? It's unclear. You can format *escape* and *urlencode* as code samples if you want to emphasise the facts that they PHP functions.

Answer (score 0):

Url encode the string you pass inside query parameter like:
`?query=%22q1%3D1%26q2%3D2%26q3%3D3%22`

```
$s = $_GET['query'];
parse_str(trim($s,'"'),  $output);
print_r($output);
```

Output is:

```
Array ( [q1] => 1 [q2] => 2 [q3] => 3 )
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by providing the code that encode the query parameters. While the output is interesting, the important part is how you end up with the encoded parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use another separator, you could use comma for example

```
test.php?query=q1,q2,q3
$parameters = explode(',', $_GET['query']);
```

if you need those parameters to have a value, why don't you use json? But you will have to (or at least shoud) urlencode your json object first

```
test.php?query={"q1":1,"q2":2,"q3":3} // raw json
test.php?query=%7B%22q1%22%3A1%2C%22q2%22%3A2%2C%22q3%22%3A3%7D //encoded json

$parameters = json_decode( urldecode($_GET['query']) );
```

To encode your parameters, simply use json_encode and urlencode

```
$array = array( "q1" => 1, "q2" => 2, "q3" => 3 );
$parameters = urlencode( json_encode($array) );
```